# My Ether wallet keystore file

Tags: keystore

My computer charging port broke and my computer is dead along with my Keystore file. I have everything written down can anyone tell me how I can access my ETH. Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you have? https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info - there are options to access it

Answer (score 1):

As @rstormsf mentions, it might be possible if you still have your mnemonic phrase to regenerate your key.

If you don't have that phrase and don't have your private key, according to [their documentation on their KB](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/i-only-have-my-address-and-password-can-i-access-my-account) there is nothing that can be done.  If it wasn't your hard drive that "broke" you, or maybe someone with the skills can still recover that file.  I'd get in touch with a *good* tech as soon as you can if your balance worth it.